# c++ program returning a default 0

Tags: c++, class, object

i finished writing this beginner c++ program that is basically just a rectangle class. the program compiles just fine, the only problem i am having with it is that it is returning a zero for the width and i cant figure out why. i would really appreciate if someone could tell me where i have gone wrong and help me out.

```
#pragma once
class theRectangle
{
private:
    int height;
    int width;

public:


    theRectangle();

    theRectangle(int _height, int _width);

    int calcArea() const;

    int calcPerimeter() const;

    bool is_Square()const;

    int Get_Height() const;

    void Set_Height(int _hight);

    int Get_Width() const;

    void Set_Width(int _width);

};



#include "theRectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//default constructor
theRectangle::theRectangle()
{
    height = 0;
    width = 0;
}

//parameterized constructor
theRectangle::theRectangle(int _height, int _width)
{

    height = _height;
    width = _width;

}
//get height function
int theRectangle::Get_Height() const
{

    return height;
}
//get width function
int theRectangle::Get_Width() const
{

    return width;
}

//calculate area function
int theRectangle::calcArea() const
{
    return (height*width);
}
//calculate perimiter function
int theRectangle::calcPerimeter() const
{
    return (height+height+width+width);
}
//is square function
bool theRectangle::is_Square()const
{
    if(height == width)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//set height function
void theRectangle::Set_Height(int _height)
{
    height = _height;
}
//set width function
void theRectangle::Set_Width(int _width)
{
    height = _width;
}





#include "theRectangle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void printRectangle(const theRectangle& rec);

int main()
{



    theRectangle rectangleONE;
    int number;
    int numbertwo;


    cout << "\n Please type the height the 1st rectangle:  ";
    cin >> number;
    rectangleONE.Set_Height(number);
    cout << "\n Please type the width of the 1st rectangle: ";
    cin >> numbertwo;
    rectangleONE.Set_Width(numbertwo);


    theRectangle rectangleTWO;
    int numberthree;
    int numberfour;
    //ask user/save data
    cout << "\n Please type the height of the 2nd rectangle:  ";
    cin >> numberthree;
    rectangleTWO.Set_Height(numberthree);
    cout << "\n Please type the width of the 2nd rectangle: ";
    cin >> numberfour;
    rectangleTWO.Set_Width(numberfour);


    theRectangle rectangleTHREE;
    int numberfive;
    int numbersix;


    cout << "\n Please type the height of the 3rd rectangle:  ";
    cin >> numberfive;
    rectangleTHREE.Set_Height(numberfive);
    cout << "\n Please type the width of the 3rd rectangle:  ";
    cin >> numbersix;
    rectangleTHREE.Set_Width(numbersix);

    //print data
    cout << "\nFor rectangle one: ";
    printRectangle(rectangleONE);
    cout << "\nFor rectangle two: ";
    printRectangle(rectangleTWO);
    cout << "\nFor rectangle three: ";
    printRectangle(rectangleTHREE);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


//print rectangle function
// Purpose: print info on rectangle
// Parameters:none
// Returns: none
void printRectangle(const theRectangle& rec)
{
    cout << "\nHeight is:  "    << rec.Get_Height();
    cout << "\nWidth is:  "     << rec.Get_Width();
    cout << "\nArea is:  "      << rec.calcArea();
    cout << "\nPerimeter is:  " << rec.calcPerimeter();
    if (rec.is_Square())
        cout << "\n This rectangle is a Square. ";  

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `setWidth` function is actually setting your `height` member variable, leaving the `width` member set to 0:

```
//set width function
void theRectangle::Set_Width(int _width)
{
    height = _width;
}
```

It should be:

```
//set width function
void theRectangle::Set_Width(int _width)
{
    width = _width;
}
```

Comment: @JayRogers Glad to help. Mistakes like this are easy to make and, fortunately, easy to solve. If my answer helped, please accept it by clicking the green tick next to it. Thanks.